# Limit of factorial how to continue

Tags: calculus, limits, factorial

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\dfrac{(n+1)^{n+1}\cdot n!}{2^{(n+1)!-n!}}\right)=\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\dfrac{(n+1)^{n+1}\cdot n!}{2^{n!\cdot n}}\right).$$

How to continue?
the answer is $0$ ... thank you

Comment: $$\frac{(n+1)^{n+1}n!}{2^{n\cdot n!}}=\frac{(n+1)^n \cdot (n+1)!}{(2^{n\cdot (n-1)!})^n}$$

$$=\left(\frac{n+1}{2^n}\right)^n\frac{(n+1)!}{2^{n\cdot (n-1)!}}$$

Comment: and how i get answer 0 ?

Comment: This is <$$\frac {n+1}{2^n}\frac{n+1}{2^{(n-1)!}}$$

Comment: i dont understand how we got this

Comment: this is the regular excercise 
![enter image description here][1]


  [1]: http://i.stack.imgur.com/Rzqv4.gif

maybe i made error in way

Answer (score 1):

If you take the natural log we get

$$ \ln(a_n)=(n+1)\ln(n+1)+\ln(n!)-( (n+1)!-n! )\ln(2)$$

$$= (n+1)\ln(n+1)+\sum_{1}^{n}\ln(k)-n\,n!\ln(2) $$

$$ = (n+1)\ln(n+1)+n\ln(n)-n+1-n\,n!\ln(2) \sim_{ \infty} 2n\ln(n)-n-nn!\,\ln(2) $$

$$  = 2n\ln(n)-(n+1)!\,\ln(2) \to -\infty $$

$$ \implies a_n \rightarrow_{n\to\infty} 0 $$

**Note:**

> $$ \sum_{1}^{n}\ln(k) \sim \int_{1}^{n} \ln(x) dx =n\ln(n)+n-1. $$

Comment: we didnt know this answer

Comment: @user165210: It is an approach. These are useful techniques to learn.